# How to delete/invalidate a php session different to the current one

Tags: php, session

I want to prevent my user to login my website from multiple browsers simultaneously. The server backend is written in php. The Idea is that I invalidate any session for that user when he logs in again.

To know which session the user has last logged in, I store the session id in a mysql database (as a VARCHAR).

But how can I invalidate a session different to  the current one in php?

Comment: your session should invalidate itself: storing the new session id would cause a request with the old session ID to fail, or am i missing something?

Comment: You just need to compare the one in the database with the one in the `$_SESSION` variable.  If they don't match, log the user out.

Answer (score 1):

Please check some good answer already provided on the below URls

[How to prevent multiple logins in PHP website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727919/how-to-prevent-multiple-logins-in-php-website)

[How to prevent multiple user login with same user name and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565413/how-to-prevent-multiple-user-login-with-same-user-name-and-password)

Comment: You can simply set a flag in the database and check this flag every time. If flag is set this means user is loggedin.